# SPI NAND rewrite issue

Tags: stm32, spi, nand, nand-flash

I'm using Alliance Memory's AS5F38G04SND-08LIN 8Gbit(1 Gbyte) SLC NAND flash with STM32.

[Datasheet](https://www.alliancememory.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/flash/AllianceMemory_SPI_NAND_Flash_July2020_Rev1.0.pdf)

So my question is, Can I re-write a page with data already in it? Page size is 4096 bytes.

For example: if after block erase I write first 256 bytes at location 0-256, and then write another 256 bytes at location 256-512, then first write data's(at location 0-256) first 4 bytes are damaged.

Does it mean that I can not use the same page twice?

To program I did use

1. 06H (WRITE ENABLE)
2. Program Load (PL) (02H)
3. 10H (PROGRAM EXECUTE)
4. 0FH (GET FEATURE command to read the status)

To READ I did use

1. 13H (Page Read to Cache)
2. 0FH (GET FEATURE
   command to read the status)
3. 03H Read from Cache memory

Also, I did check SPI bus via logic analyzer and it's look ok.

My Program code looks like

```
u8 AS5FXX_Program(u16 addr_c, u8 addr_p, u16 addr_b, u8* buffer, u16 num_byte)
{
u8 err = ERROR_NO;
u8 tx_buff[4];

// addr_c - cell address
// addr_p - page address
/ /addr_b - block address


//
// Write Enable
//

err = AS5FXX_WE();
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//
// Program Load / Program Load x4 IO
//

tx_buff[0] = AS5F_OPCODE_PROGRAM_LOAD;
tx_buff[1] = (addr_c >> 0x08U) & 0x00FFU;
tx_buff[2] = addr_c & 0x00FFU;

ASF5_CS(CS_LOW)

err = HAL_SPI_Transmit(as5fxx_cfg_.spi.handle, tx_buff, 0x03U, as5fxx_cfg_.spi.timeout);

if(err == ERROR_NO)
{
    err = HAL_SPI_Transmit(as5fxx_cfg_.spi.handle, buffer,
                           num_byte, as5fxx_cfg_.spi.timeout);
}

ASF5_CS(CS_HIGH)

if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//
// Program execute
//

u32 addr = (addr_b << 0x06) | (addr_p);

tx_buff[0] = AS5F_OPCODE_PROGRAM_EXECUTE;
tx_buff[1] = (addr >> 0x10) & 0x000000FF;
tx_buff[2] = (addr >> 0x08) & 0x000000FF;
tx_buff[3] = addr & 0x000000FF;

ASF5_CS(CS_LOW)
err = HAL_SPI_Transmit(as5fxx_cfg_.spi.handle, tx_buff, 0x04U, as5fxx_cfg_.spi.timeout);
ASF5_CS(CS_HIGH)

if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//
// Wait OIP & WEL bits
//

err = AS5FXX_Wait_Until(AS5F_REG_FEATURE_STATUS_BIT_OIP | AS5F_REG_FEATURE_STATUS_BIT_WEL);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

return err;
}
```

And My Page Read function looks like

```
u8 AS5FXX_Read(u16 addr_c, u8 addr_p, u16 addr_b, u8* buffer, u16 num_byte)
{
u8 err = ERROR_NO;
u8 tx_buff[4];

// addr_c - cell address
// addr_p - page address
/ /addr_b - block address

//
// Read to cache (NOTE 5.2.1 ~0x3F)
//

tx_buff[0] = AS5F_OPCODE_PAGE_READ_TO_CACHE;

u32 addr = (addr_b << 0x06) | (addr_p);
tx_buff[1] = (addr >> 0x10) & 0x000000FF;
tx_buff[2] = (addr >> 0x08) & 0x000000FF;
tx_buff[3] = addr & 0x000000FF;

ASF5_CS(CS_LOW)
err = HAL_SPI_Transmit(as5fxx_cfg_.spi.handle, tx_buff, 0x04U, as5fxx_cfg_.spi.timeout);
ASF5_CS(CS_HIGH)

if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//
// Wait OIP
//

err = AS5FXX_Wait_Until(AS5F_REG_FEATURE_STATUS_BIT_OIP);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//
// Read from cache
//

tx_buff[0] = AS5F_OPCODE_READ_FROM_CACHE_X1_IO_0;
tx_buff[1] = (addr_c >> 0x08U) & 0x00FFU;
tx_buff[2] = addr_c & 0x00FFU;
tx_buff[3] = 0x00;

ASF5_CS(CS_LOW)
err = HAL_SPI_Transmit(as5fxx_cfg_.spi.handle, tx_buff,
                       0x04, as5fxx_cfg_.spi.timeout);
if(err == ERROR_NO)
{
    err = HAL_SPI_Receive(as5fxx_cfg_.spi.handle, buffer,
                          num_byte, as5fxx_cfg_.spi.timeout);

}
ASF5_CS(CS_HIGH)

return err;
}
```

Comment: You do not mention what operations you do exactly and memory supports multiple types of read/write/erase operations. Generaly after erase you can change bits with value 1 to 0, but changing them from 0 to 1 requires erase. Most memories you can write multiple time. You usualy can write even already used region as long as the only bit changes are from 1 to 0. If only first 4B are broken, to me it see that you just issued wrong command. If you have logic analyzer look at bus what commands you issue to memory.

Comment: @Misaz to program I did use 
1. 06H (WRITE ENABLE)
2. Program Load (PL) (02H)
3. 10H (PROGRAM EXECUTE)
4. 0FH (GET FEATURE command to read the status)

to READ I did use

1. 13H (Page Read to Cache)
2. 0FH (GET FEATURE command to read the status)
3. 03H Read from Cache memory

Comment: @toolic yes, block 1 and block 0 are good

Comment: When writing bytes 256 to 512, try read 0 - 256 first and write 0 - 512 while writing 0 - 256 to the same values as recently read.

Comment: @Misaz what is the point of doing that?

Comment: to check that the broken 4 bytes does not come from random bytes which were in "cache memory" before writing (most probably they would not be random, but somehow related to previous operations before PL and writing).

Comment: @Misaz for example: llok at this sequence
1. write block 1, page 0. column addr 0
2. write  block 0, page 0.column addr 0
3. write block 1, page 0. column addr 256
4. erase block 0
5. write  block 0, page 0.column addr 0

then block 1, page 0, column addr 0 to 256 first 4 bytes are corrupted.

Comment: I do not see error directly, except in your question you mention that page size is 4096 bytes, but it is not. It is 4352 bytes accroding to datasheet. Additionaly you write block 0 and 1, but blocks are 278528 (4352 * 64) bytes far away. Are you sure that you write and then read the same cells? See memory layout description in linked datasheet at page 10. Note that the memory has gaps in the address space. Your question still miss lot of details. What are data you write? Do you try some pattern or random data? How does the bits of first 4 broken bytes change? Post expected and actual values.

Comment: @Misaz About GAPS in the address space, do you mean Table 1-4. ECC Protection and Spare Area for Page size [4096 + 256 bytes]  at page 13?

Comment: I mean Figure 1-5 at page 10. Allowed bytes in page are from 0 to 4351, not 0 to 4095.

Comment: @Misaz yes but I'm not using the whole page, I'm using only 512 bytes, 0-256, 256-512.
by the way when I'm using  block address, I'm using just indices, for example block 0 addr is 0, block 1 addr is 1, and calculating the whole ROW address via 6.3 Program Execute (PE) (10H) Page 31.(same for pages ). Seems I should not use indices and calculate block addresses according memory layout?

Comment: What is "indice"? I do not see this term used anywhere in the datasheet. You can give a try with address computing.

Comment: @Misaz to describe block addresses I have only 11 bits and max value is 4095. for pages I have 6 bits max value is 63, and for cells I have 12 bits max value is 8191 BUT I can use only 4395.
So for example I want to use block 1, page 0 , what block/page addresses should I use? tell me please. Also please look at page 31 where block/page addresses are used.

Comment: @Misaz You said "blocks are 278528 (4352 * 64) bytes far away" according this, block 1 address starts at location 278528 BUT It does not fits in 11 bit block address space.

Comment: According to descriptions in datasheet, every command require different address. For example, PAGE READ (13H) requires row address (RA) consisting of block and page number (see Figure 1-5) while actual READ FROM CACHE (03H) requires column address (and wrap bits, see Table 5-2). PROGRAM LOAD (02H) requires column address (and wrap bits) and PROGRAM EXECUTE (10H) requires row address. BLOICK ERASE (D8H) requires row address. So for reading block 1, page 0, byte 0 you should use PAGE READ(addr=0x0040) and READ FROM CACHE(addr=0).

Comment: It is not 11-bit, but 12-bit and it is not block, but column address. You never enters full address to this field. 12-bit column address is used for address byte inside single block. For selecting block/page you need to use row address.

Comment: @Misaz Please look at my Program/Read page source code, I updated the question.

so when I want to write inside block 1 I'm just calling AS5FXX_Program(0, 0, 1, tx_buffer, 256);

and when I want to read block 1 I'm calling AS5FXX_Read(0, 0, 1, rx_buffer, 256);

Also block address has 12 bits too <17:6> and page <5:0> please look at page 10

Comment: Code seems almost ok to me. In code you have comment `// Program Load / Program Load x4 IO` but you use x1 IO. Do you use correct opcode? Do you have logic analyzer for checking that transaction on the bus look ok? I recommed using HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive instead of spliting transmit and receiving calls separately, because depending on SPI configuration they may be unattended transitions which causes additional edges at start/end of transfer when CS is low. Additionaly, some STM32 (you do not mention family/model) has QSPI peripheral which is more optimized for this kind of chips.

Comment: @Misaz it's just wrong comment, I do use only Program Load, not X4. I did check everything via Logic Analyzer and EVERY transaction is ok. I''ll try TransmitReceive. 
STM32F407VET6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149523/discussion-between-alatriste-and-misaz).

Comment: @Misaz I want to talk about WRAP bits, as I guess I can ONLY WRITE/READ 4352 bytes, according Table 5-2, page 21 in DataSheet, please look . Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using Alliance Memory's AS5F38G04SND-08LIN 8Gbit(1 Gbyte) SLC NAND flash with STM32.
>
> [Datasheet](https://www.alliancememory.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/flash/AllianceMemory_SPI_NAND_Flash_July2020_Rev1.0.pdf)
>
> So my question is, Can I re-write a page with data already in it? Page size is 4096 bytes.

With that device, **no**.

Or to be a bit more accurate, the device specification in the datasheet does not allow that usage. So if you attempt to do it, as you are, then anything (including *appearing* to work completely or partially) is possible.

> For example: if after block erase I write first 256 bytes at location 0-256, and then write another 256 bytes at location 256-512, then first write data's(at location 0-256) first 4 bytes are damaged.

That sequence is not supported so any result, including that one, is possible.

The relevant part of the datasheet linked above, is this (adapted from the full table 10-3):

[image: parameter page data structure, address 110, number of programs per page]

As you see, it shows that "Number of programs per page" is 1. That means that only 1 program operation is allowed per page, before a block erase is required.

You are trying to do more than 1 program operation per page. As that is outside the device specification, anything could happen (as I explained above).

---

There's a bit of explanation in the ONFI specification about that parameter. I don't know which version of ONFI that device supports (I couldn't see it mentioned in the datasheet and in table 10-3 in that datasheet, it seems to show the reserved value of 0 in address 4-5 for the supported ONFI revision number).

Therefore it may not be the *exact* ONFI version supported by that device, but here is an extract of the description of the "Number of programs per page" parameter from the [Open NAND Flash Interface Specification, Revision 4.2, dated 02 12 2020, downloaded from Micron](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/onfi/specs/onfi_4_2-gold.pdf):

[image: description of "number of programs per page" from ONFI specification revision 4.2]

As you see, the value of 1 for the device you are using, indicates that programming multiple parts of a page between block erases is not supported.

I remember some of the flash devices I used had a value of 4 for that parameter, so there are devices which allow what you are trying to do - just not that device you have.

---

Finally: I have not reviewed your code or algorithm, since I could answer the question without the code. Whether the code is implementing the correct commands in the correct order or not, the device is being operated outside its specification, if you attempt to program a page more than once without a block erase.

Comment: the KEY word is THE SAME PORTION, so when I'm trying to program 0-256, then 256-512, it's not the SAME portion. 
for example, when I'm doing this:  
EraseBlock(PAGE0);
 AS5FXX_Program(0, PAGE0, BLOCK1, tx_buffer, 256);
AS5FXX_Program(256, PAGE0, BLOCK1, tx_buffer, 256);

Then it works OK. BUT if I program block 0, BETWEEN block 1 programs, then I got damaged data in block 1. Look at this: 
EraseBlock(PAGE0);
 AS5FXX_Program(0, PAGE0, BLOCK1, tx_buffer, 256);
EraseBlock(BLOCK0);
AS5FXX_Program(0, PAGE0, BLOCK0, data, 4);
AS5FXX_Program(256, PAGE0, BLOCK1, tx_buffer, 256);

Comment: @Alatriste - Hi, I am not saying that you are programming the *same* portion of a page. That last sentence of the details in the ONFI spec that I copied, does not apply in your case. It's all the paragraph *above* that sentence, which is relevant to you. I didn't want to start cutting out text which could be useful to other people. Is my intent clearer now? (To be extra clear - you are still trying to program multiple, different parts *of the same page* (without doing a block erase) - and that functionality is not supported on that device, but is supported on some others.)

Comment: yes clear.. got it

Comment: Now I'm writing in different pages and block, for example
Write(0, PAGE0, BLOCK0);
Write(0, PAGE1, BLOCK1);

BUT when I'm reading both pages, I have PAGE0 data into the PAGE1(at the begining of PAGE1). note that I'm writing in different blocks. is it possible that FLASH is damaged somehow?

Comment: I want to talk about WRAP bits, as I guess I can ONLY WRITE/READ 4352 bytes, according Table 5-2, page 21 in DataSheet, please look . Am I right?